# Linq2sql table: List<fieldname> as parameter

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

So, I want to update certain fields of my items table:

```
internal void FieldsUpdate(string id, System.Collections.Hashtable fieldsWithChanges, List<string> keysToUpdate)
{
    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        item myItem = db.items.Single(t=>t.id==id);
        keysToUpdate.ForEach(key => {
            myItem[key] = GetValue(fieldsWithChanges, key).ToString(); 
            //Or something like that, I'm inventing that index 
        });
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

`myItem[key]` does not exist, so how should I do this?

This is the awful option that I know of:

```
internal void FieldsUpdate(string id, System.Collections.Hashtable fieldsWithChanges, List<string> keysToUpdate)
{
    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        item myItem = db.items.Single(t=>t.id==id);
        keysToUpdate.ForEach(key => {
            if (key=="thisKey")
                myItem.thisKey = GetValue(fieldsWithChanges, key).ToString(); 
                // really awful. So What this condition for every colname? thats unsustainable.
        });
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Is `keys` supposed to be `keysToUpdate`?

Comment: You 're right, sry. (that's not the issue however, but i'll change it to avoid confusion) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the property value using reflection.

```
internal void FieldsUpdate(string id, System.Collections.Hashtable fieldsWithChanges, List<string> keysToUpdate)
{
    using (DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext())
    {
        item myItem = db.items.Single(t=>t.id==id);
        keysToUpdate.ForEach(key => {
            typeof(item).GetProperty(key)
                .SetValue(item, GetValue(fieldsWithChanges, key), null);
        });
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

This will not be the most performant of solutions.

I would recommend looking into code generation if this is a pattern you need to maintain.

Comment: You mean going reflection all the way?, maintainability is also an issue, and that's why I've always tried to avoid it. This does the trick, nonetheless, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by all the way.  I have editted my answer to be a bit more clear.  The solution will work, but will be slow for large amounts of updates.

Comment: I have another issue: `GetValue` returns an `object`, but the `Hashtable` value for the `key` is another `type` (which is actually the same type as on destiny key field)... Will the encapsulation into object and decapsulation go without any castings necessary? or should I be thinking on a <T> method?

Comment: If it is of the same type, it will.  Try it and let me know the result :)